# get data from multiple collection using array of key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i want data of orders collection where order _id =1 and her inventId object with it...
i want the same output, i attach all of the code given blow  please check and make a query for me...  which response is same as i want
**Orders Collection**

```
 [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "almonds",
      "price": 12,
      "inventId": [
        {
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2
        },
        
      ],
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "item": "pecans",
      "price": 32,
      "inventId": [
        {
          "id": 1
        },
      
        
      ],
    }
  ],
```

**inventoryCollection**

```
 "inventory": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "sku": "almonds",
      "description": "product 1",
      "instock": 120
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "sku": "bread",
      "description": "product 2",
      "instock": 80
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "sku": "cashews",
      "description": "product 3",
      "instock": 60
    },
  ]
```

and the output which i want..

```
[
  {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "almonds",
      "price": 12,
      "quantity": 2,
      "inventory_docs":[
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "description": "product 1",
          "instock": 120,
          "sku": "almonds"
        }, {
          "_id": 2,
          "description": "product 2",
          "instock": 80,
          "sku": "bread"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: _"and make a query for me"_. That's not how this works.

Comment: this query is related to mongo db  and node js

Answer (score 0):

this query same as you want...

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: 1
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$inventId"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inventory",
      "localField": "inventId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "inventory_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$inventory_docs"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "item": {
        "$first": "$item"
      },
      "price": {
        "$first": "$price"
      },
      "quantity": {
        "$first": "$quantity"
      },
      "matchDocs": {
        "$push": "$inventory_docs"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "almonds",
    "matchDocs": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "description": "product 1",
        "instock": 120,
        "sku": "almonds"
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "description": "product 2",
        "instock": 80,
        "sku": "bread"
      }
    ],
    "price": 12,
    "quantity": 2
  }
]
```